# How to write dictionary to file as json

Tags: node.js

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    link: '/listing/vasita-otomobil-audi-sahibinden-tertemiz-a3-sedan-849052103/detail',
    timestamp: 2020-09-02T16:26:41.007Z
  },
  {
    link: '/listing/vasita-otomobil-opel-mennan-autodan-opel-vectra-hatasiz-2008-lpgli-temiz-bakimli-856921177/detail',
    timestamp: 2020-09-02T16:26:41.007Z
  },
  {
    link: '/listing/vasita-otomobil-opel-2012-model-opel-corsa-1.3-cdti-essentia-75-ps-856923040/detail',
    timestamp: 2020-09-02T16:26:41.007Z
  },
  {
    link: '/listing/vasita-otomobil-fiat-kirca-otomotiv-2005-fiat-panda-cam-tavanli-otomatik-vites-856922600/detail',
    timestamp: 2020-09-02T16:26:41.007Z
  },..]
```

I want to be able to save it as it in json file. I do it like this:

```
fs.writeFile('links.json', fs.write(JSON.stringify(pendingLinks)));
```

It is giving this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "fd" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('"[object Object],[object...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error due to the incorrect syntax of `fs.write`. All you need to do to write the content into the file is:

```
fs.writeFile('links.json', JSON.stringify(pendingLinks), (err) => console.log(err);
```

You may want to check the docs for `writeFile` and `writeFileSync`[enter link description here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Comment: And what to do for append fs.appendFileSync('links.json', JSON.stringify(pendingLinks))

Comment: ah, you cannot just append like that, because then you will end up having 2 arrays one after the other which is not valid json

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error. [You just need to open file for first and add 'a' for activate append mode](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-write-method/) ("data will be appended to the output file instead of overwriting the existing data"), if you want that.

```
fs.open(__dirname+'/links.json', 'a', function(err, fd) {
  if (err) console.log ('cant open file');
  else {
    fs.write(fd, JSON.stringify(pendingLinks), function(err, writtenbytes) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      else console.log(writtenbytes);
    });
  }
});
```

In syntax 'fd' (in code: __dirname+'/links.json') is a data's destination file.

Comment: No, there is no need for `fs.open` you can just do `fs.writeFile(filename, content, errorhandler)`

Comment: @derpirscher, yes... when i wrote ans, i didnt know about `fs.appendFile` method or the possibility to insert flags ('a', 'r') into writing function itself (like: `fs.writeFile(path, content, {flag: 'a'}, callback)`, i.e. i use `fs.open` only for 'a' flag. if question's author doesnt want sequential recording to the file, yes, let he use base `fs.writeFile`